# How to implement an in-memory cache using RxJava2 and Room Persistence Library?

Tags: android, rx-java2, android-room

I've a list of rate-able items. There are items with different colors. The user can select different colors and the app will retrieve and show the items of the color.

I have a method to retrieve items of a particular color from the Room database. When the user rates an item, I update Room which then pushes the updated items to the method.

Right now, there's a perceptible lag between rating an item and seeing the changes reflected on the app.

How do I implement an in-memory cache using RxJava2 that plays along well with Room?

Comment: "Right now, there's a perceptible lag between rating an item and seeing the changes reflected on the app" - isn't this the real question, especially as it is a local persisted db there should not be a lag when inserting/updating rows and room/rxjava notifying of the change?

Comment: @MarkKeen I don't know why there is a delay. The delay is not too large. It's just that when the user presses the upvote/downvote button for an item, the visual feedback occurs slightly after the finger has left the screen. I want to make the rating process feel instantaneous

Comment: I do not think a cache can solve the problem, because the lag occur when an item is updated, and a cache cannot make updating faster, only reading previously stored items.

Comment: I had an idea of storing the data I'm displaying in a list. Whenever the data is to be updated, it update the data in the list and then update the database. Since updating the list is really fast, there isn't any lag. Once the database is updated, it emits its items which overwrite those of the list.